# Laplace transform of convolution when upper limit is infinity

Tags: laplace-transform

The common statement of the Laplace transform for the convolution is:

$$ L(f*g)(s) = F(s)G(s), $$

where

$$ (f*g)(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\, d\tau. $$

Can this property be used for a convolution where the upper limit is infinity? Can the Laplace transform of:

$$ (f*g)(t) = \int_0^\infty f(\tau)g(t-\tau)\, d\tau $$

be expressed in a similar fashion as the product of the individual transforms of $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you take the upper limit to be $\infty$. Then for $\tau>t$ you’d be considering $g(t)$ for $t<0$. But the Laplace transform of $g(t)$ is only taken over positive times, and so cannot carry any information about $g(t)$ during this time. Hence there’s no way that the “full-time convolution” can be expressed in terms of the Laplace transforms of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

Notes:

1) This issue pertains to the one-sided transform. The two-sided transform doesn’t have this quirk since it extends over all times.

2) One quirk of the “full-time convolution” is that it is manifestly asymmetric between $f$ and $g$: the substitution $\tau’=t-\tau$ does not swap $f$ and $g$ owing to the integration endpoints. Hence one would have $f\ast g\neq g\ast f$, which is hardly appealing.

3) One “exception” to the above is if you insist that $g(t)$ and $f(t)$ both vanish for $t<0$. Under that convention the convolution can be written in the usual way as an integral over the real line. But the integrand is still only supported for $\tau\in[0,t]$ so there’s really no point.

Comment: thank you for your answer. What about for the bilateral Laplace transform could I use that one instead? I am trying to solve a system of integral equations where the convolution up until infinity shows up, and I am deciding whether to use Laplace, or Fourier transforms to solve this system

Comment: You could use bilateral Laplace, yes. But the bilateral Laplace transform is intimately linked with the Fourier transform; indeed, one may use the former to _define_ the latter (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform#Relationship_to_other_integral_transforms). So there's not much formal difference between them, though the domain of analyticity is different (convergence in strip along the imaginary vs. real axis).